# How to get highest count from list data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

i have a query like this :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(o.created_at, '%Y-%m') as date,
JSON_EXTRACT(oi.inventory, '$.id') as inv_id,
count(JSON_EXTRACT(oi.inventory, '$.id')) as inv_count
from orders as o inner join order_items as oi on oi.order_id = o.id
where o.created_at >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE())) DAY) - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND
o.created_at < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE())) DAY) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
group by date, inv_id 
order by date desc limit 10
```

and the result is :

| date | inv_id | inv_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 1 | 22 |
| 2023-01 | 2 | 29 |
| 2022-12 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-12 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-11 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-11 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-10 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-10 | 2 | 1 |

but all i want is result like this :

| date | inv_id | inv_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 2 | 29 |
| 2022-12 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-11 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-10 | 1 | 2 |

how to grouping data like that? because i can't use `max(inv_count)` inside group by

Comment: why you don't ``select data,inv_id,max(inv_count) from (yourquery) a group by data,inv_id``

Comment: Which version of MySQL? It matters because `MySQL 8` has functionality not present in `MySQL 5.x`. Also, will there only ever be TWO inv_id values?

Comment: i'm using mysql 5.7.26

Comment: it can be more than two, but the point is, i want to get highest count value per month and the inv_id

Comment: @EvanMahendra Then there are no 'clean' options. I recommend storing the full results in a temporary table and then using one of the many `greatest-n-per-group` answers from SO, for example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql/1313293#1313293

Comment: @MatBailie okay i'll try to store the result in a temporary table first, thank you Mat